# How to fetch data from the webview that can be used in android activity?

Tags: javascript, java, android, html, webview

I've been searching for a solution like my problem, yet couldn't find one. I want to fetch some data from my webview inside my android activity as i am closing webview activity after successful login. I need to access the employee code in the html below. How can I do this?

```
!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Landing Page</title>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
    <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10">

    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/trailloader.css"> -->

    <script src="scripts/jquery_min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


    <script src="scripts/bootstrap-dialog.min.js"></script>


     <script src="scripts/Encryption.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/aes.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/require.js"></script>
     <script src="scripts/core_crypto.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/sha256.js"></script>
    <!-- <script src="scripts/Encryption.js"></script> -->
    <script src="scripts/common.js"></script>



    </head>

    <script>

    $(function() {
    //alert('dass');
    //var ssivd = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(16);    
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
               $.support.cors = true
    var request = $.ajax({
        //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: 'https://customapps-uat.WsFederation_SSO/api/Auth/SamlResponse',

        type: "GET",
        crossDomain: true,
       // data: JSONObject,
        dataType: "jsonp",
        xhrFields: {
           withCredentials: true
      },
      crossDomain: true,
      beforeSend: function(xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Cookie", "session=xxxyyyzzz");
      },
        contentType :"application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        async: false,
        success: function onDataReceived(data) {

             console.log(data)
             //document.cookie = "Clienturl=https://dms-uat.mywebsite.net/MyCab_SSO/newlanding.html";
             var ssivd = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(
            var EmpID = data.EmpID;
                $("#para").text(EmpID);
            sessionStorage.Flag='Y'
                 if(data.AtosEmpDetails.SyntelEmpID == "") {
                    sessionStorage.USER_ID = data.AtosEmpDetails.DAS_ID;
                    }
                    else{
                    console.log("Syntel id:"+data.AtosEmpDetails.SyntelEmpID);
                    sessionStorage.USER_ID = data.AtosEmpDetails.SyntelEmpID;
                }
            //alert(flag)
            if(flag == 0)
            {

            }
            if(flag == 1)
            {
              sessionStorage.EMPNAME = (data.Name).toUpperCase();
             // alert(sessionStorage.EMPNAME);
              //sessionStorage.Flag='Y';

              lan_id = data.EmpID;
              console.log("Lanid:"+lan_id);
              $("#para").text(SyntelEmpID);
              window.location.href = "newsso.html"


            } 
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, status, exception) {
            hideLoader();
            BootstrapDialog.show({
                //title: 'MyCab',
                title: 'Quiz',
                message: 'Something went wrong'
            });
            // alert(status);

        }

    });



}   
/*SSO code Ends*/
);


function encryptVal(valtoEncrypt){

    sskey = localStorage.ch;
    var ssivd = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(16);  

    var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(valtoEncrypt, sskey,{
    iv: ssivd
});


return encrypted;

}

function decryptVal(encrypted){

    sskey = localStorage.ch;
    var ssivd = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(16);  

var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted, sskey,{
    iv: ssivd
});


return decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);

}



    </script>
    <body>
    <p id="para"></p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

and Android code of webactivity:

```
public class WebActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView webview;
    private static final String TAG = "Main";
    private ProgressDialog progressBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_web);
        Toast.makeText(WebActivity.this, "hello", 1);
         webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
         WebSettings settings = webview.getSettings();
            settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webview.clearCache(true);
            webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
            webview.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
            webview.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
            webview.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
            webview.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
            webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {

                CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();

                cookieManager.setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(webview, true);

            }
            final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();

            progressBar = ProgressDialog.show(WebActivity.this, "Please wait..", "Loading...");

            webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Processing webview url click...");
                    if(url.contains("https://mywebsite.net/Snap/newsso.html") ) {
                        Intent i = new Intent(WebActivity.this,UploadActivity.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                        finish();
                    }
                    else {
                    view.loadUrl(url);}
                    return true;
                }

                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Finished loading URL: " + url);
                    progressBar.dismiss();
                    if(url.contains("https://mywebsite.net/Snap/newsso.html")) {
                        Intent i = new Intent(WebActivity.this,UploadActivity.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                        finish();
                    }
                }


                public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + description);
                    Toast.makeText(WebActivity.this, "Oh no! " + description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    alertDialog.setTitle("Error");
                    alertDialog.setMessage(description);
                    alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            return;
                        }
                    });
                    alertDialog.show();
                }
            });

            webview.loadUrl("https://mywebsite.net/Snap/snapsso.html");
        }}
```